# A question about decomposing mod 2 modular forms of level p^2

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, characteristic-p, power-series

Fix an odd prime $p$. Each $f \in \mathbb{Z}/2[[x]]$ can be written as $f_{+} + f_{-} + f_0$ where each exponent k of $x$ appearing in $f_{+}$ (resp. $f_{-}$, $f_0$) has Legendre symbol $(k/p)$ equal to 1 (resp. -1, 0).

When $f$ is a "characteristic 2 modular form for $\Gamma_0(p)$", the same need not hold for $f_{+}$, $f_{-}$, and $f_0$.

QUESTION: When $f$ is a characteristic 2 modular form for $\Gamma_0(p^2)$, is the same true of $f_{+}$, $f_{-}$ and $f_0$?

Remarks: The answer to the question is yes when $p$ is 3 or 5. One can give a formulation of the question free from any reference to modular forms since the space of characteristic 2 modular forms of level $p^2$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}/2[F,G,H]$ in its field of fractions,
where $F=x+x^9+x^{25}+x^{49}+...$ and $G=F(x^p)$, $H=G(x^p)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, if $f$ is a characteristic zero modular form of level $p^{2}$ then $f_{+}$, $f_{-}$ and $f_{0}$ are also characteristic zero modular forms of level $p^{2}$.

We have $f_{0} = f | U(p) | V(p)$, and since $f$ has level $p^{2}$, $f | U(p)$ has level $p$ and then $f | U(p) | V(p)$ has level $p^{2}$.

Also, since $f = \sum a(n) q^{n}$, $f_{\chi} = \sum \chi(n) a(n) q^{n}$ has level $p^{2}$ if $\chi$ is the Legendre symbol modulo $p$. This follows, for example, by Theorem 7.4 from Iwaniec's "Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms". Since $f_{+} = \frac{1}{2} (f - f_{0}) + \frac{1}{2} f_{\chi}$, we have that $f_{+}$ also has level $p^{2}$. Then $f_{-} = f - f_{0} - f_{+}$ also has level $p^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy--despite my looking at Stein's database, the thought that this should hold in characteristic zero never struck.I haven't looked at the argument in Iwaniec yet, but will.